# Java - select from array of values

Tags: java, mysql

I was wondering if it is possible to do a `select *` where value is in Java `String[]` or do I need to build a string of values from the string array first?

I am trying to find the best way of doing this technically without singular selects or building a string of values from the array.

Thanks for your time.

```
String[] lookupValues = new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "4"};
Select * from database where value in (lookupvalues)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do? Do you want do filter an String[]?

Comment: How are you sending your query from Java to MySQL? Where's the JDBC?

Answer (score 1):

try `Arrays.toString(lookupvalues)` or write a utility function.

```
    public String toString(String[] values, boolean addQuotes) {

        StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder();
        for(String value : values) {
            if(addQuotes) {
                buff.append(String.format("\"%s\"", value)).append(",");
            } else {
                buff.append(value).append(",");
            }
        }
        buff.deleteCharAt(buff.length()-1); // delete the last comma
        return buff.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is not a direct answer to your question considering only arrays. I suggest you to use [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) since it offers a implementation of filter on Java `Collection`s. Using proven libraries will give you flexibility if you use different kind of filters.

You can easily convert your array into proper collection

```
String[] lookupValues = new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "4"};
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(lookupValues));
```

And filter it with Guava filters:

```
Collection<String> filtered = Collections2.filter(list,
    Predicates.containsPattern("3"));
print(filtered);
```

will find

```
3
```

If you want filtered collection as a list, you can use this something like this from Guava:

```
List<String> filteredList = Lists.newArrayList(Collections2.filter(
    list, Predicates.containsPattern("3")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to search for a string in array? If yes, you might want to look at `Collections.binarySearch()` or `Arrays.binarySearch()` - but please not that the collections or arrays need to be sorted before doing binary search